# What are the names of power supply connectors in this picture?

Tags: pcb, connector, ground, vcc, lna

[image]

What are the names of power supply connectors in this picture?

Comment: Almost identical question was posted a few days ago. Can you search for it?

Comment: You are right. I saw it now.

Comment: These are not swaged  or press fit turret terminals as suggested by duplicate, FYI @Community

Comment: The Vcc one looks like a feed trough capacitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call them “bulkhead turrets” or case-mounted turrets or “stand-off and feed-through” power and ground terminals.

But it appears some Mfg’s call them “ Threaded Turret Standardized Terminals”

“ PCB solder pin with threaded feedthru pin” for power ?
“Threaded double turret” for gnd..?

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don’t know what you are referring  to.